# Enable the ability to create resource groups

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to give members of a specific role the ability to create resource groups. Can this be achieved without giving users the co-owner role at the subscription level?

Answer (score 0):

You can grant them [contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) rights on the specific Azure subscription, they don't have to be co-owner. This is the least-privilege built-in role available that allows you to create resource groups.

However, you could also create a custom role with only one action:

```
Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write
```

Read more here: [Custom roles for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles)